# Install Stretch package in Buster?

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-buster

I used Camorama in Raspbian Stretch to take pictures with a webcam. But in Buster, apt does not list the camorama package.
Camorama uses an overlay (I think) to display, so using my [virtual machine script](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=251757) would not help.
All the other webcam capture programs I tried have excessive latency and use lots of CPU.

Is there any way to install camorama in Buster? Or am I out of luck?

Comment: you could build from source if it's not in the buster repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Camorama is not available for Debian Buster yet. You can install it from a .deb package:

First of all, you need to obtain the package, for example from [this website](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/camorama).

To download `camorama_0.19-5+b1` you can try this:

**1)** Download the package using `wget`:

*This for the* **arm64** *package:*

```
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/c/camorama/camorama_0.19-5+b1_arm64.deb
```

*or this for the* **armhf** *package:*

```
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/c/camorama/camorama_0.19-5+b1_armhf.deb
```

**2)** Install it using **`dpkg`**:

*arm64:*

```
sudo dpkg -i camorama_0.19-5+b1_arm64.deb
```

*armhf:*

```
sudo dpkg -i camorama_0.19-5+b1_armhf.deb
```

Comment: Had to install a bunch of dependencies first, but after that it worked. To be specific, gconf2 gnome-mime-data libart-2.0-2 libbonobo2-0 libbonobo2-common
  libbonoboui2-0 libbonoboui2-common libgail-common libgail18 libgnome-2-0
  libgnome-keyring-common libgnome-keyring0 libgnome2-common libgnomecanvas2-0
  libgnomecanvas2-common libgnomeui-0 libgnomeui-common libgnomevfs2-0
  libgnomevfs2-common libgnomevfs2-extra liborbit-2-0

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way that worked for me, without have to worry about resolve broken dependencies is the following

1. Open the `sources.list` with `sudo vim.tiny /etc/apt/sources.list` or any other text editor (with superuser privileges).
2. Change the repository from buster to stretch, save and close the file.
3. Run the command `sudo apt update` for apt to refresh its repository links.
4. Install camorama with `sudo apt install camorama`.
5. Change the repository from stretch back to buster in `/etc/apt/sourcs.list`.
6. Run the command `sudo apt update` again.

Done.

Answer (score 1):

Note that there is a bunch of packages which are similar to `camorama` (depending on what you actually want to do of course) and available in Buster:

- `cheese`
- `webcam`/`fswebcam`
- `stopmotion`/`qstopmotion`
- `kamerka`
- `vgrabbj`

I suppose there was a reason why they dropped `camorama` support, most probably because the project is no longer maintained and doesn't work properly with modern hardware.